# Docker container showing "not found" for entrypoint command

Tags: docker

I am just simply trying to pass some arguments to my ENTRYPOINT command, but it keep showing `not found` in its output.

Here's what my Dockerfile has at the end:

```
ENTRYPOINT "/usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent -region us-east-2 -register -code $ACTIVATION_CODE -id $ACTIVATION_ID"
```

I get the error when running the following command:

```
root@docker-test:~/# docker run -ti -e ACTIVATION_CODE=9SHHXJPYgbPaxZbnpV+ -e ACTIVATION_ID=a1a91393-b9c8-4000-b76e-e6fc9f8940b5 6977e8135eb8 /bin/bash
/bin/bash: 1: /usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent -region us-east-2 -register -code 9SHHXJPYgbPaxZbnpV+ -id a1a91393-b9c8-4000-b76e-0: not found
```

The `amazon-ssm-agent` command exists but I'm not quite sure what it means by "not found". Does that mean the command is not found or something else?

Comment: "Command not found" usually [have exit code 127](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) so this might be an error from `amazon-ssm-agent` and not necessarily directly related to Docker.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid form for the `ENTRYPOINT` directive. You can choose between the *exec* form (the preferred one) and the *shell* form. More [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

In your case:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent -region us-east-2 -register -code $ACTIVATION_CODE -id $ACTIVATION_ID"]
```

you have to call the shell (`sh`) in order to enable the variable substitution. Alternatively, the shell form:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/amazon-ssm-agent -region us-east-2 -register -code $ACTIVATION_CODE -id $ACTIVATION_ID
```